# Refused to load the stylesheet blob:https://url because it violates the CSP directive: style-src 'self' *.url unsafe-inline unsafe-eval, so style-src

Tags: html, content-security-policy

Orientation of the Screen not good i tried some meta tags but it doesnot  work
I am not getting is it front end error or server side
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=" style-src ' https://*' unsafe-inline unsafe-eval unsafe-hashes "/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you seem to be adding a policy in meta tag, while another policy is restricting your content. Adding another policy can only make the total policy stricter. You will need to modify the existing policy to relax it. When you have identified how it is set you will need to add "blob:" to style-src.

Comment: can you provide correct meta tag as per your view

Comment: You can add "blob:" to the end of the meta tag, but it won't make any difference as it doesn't pass the other existing policy

Comment: Thank-you for the help , but we are interns working on it and we r not able to pin point the exact location where and how to solve this error. We will further look into it if any problem arises we will post again.

Comment: Response headers can be set in code, web server config files, proxies, load balancers. Start looking in these places...